# Unknown column 'notifiable_id' in 'field list' - Laravel Notifications

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to understand why is this error appearing. This is my first time with Laravel's notification system and I'm getting the error above. I have been following the docummentation on Laravel's website but I can't seem to get the grip of this error.

*JobDenied*

```
 public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'deniedTime'    => Carbon::now()
    ];
}
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

*Notification tables*

```
// Generate using php artisan notifications:table
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->morphs('php ');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

*Invoking the notificaton*

```
$sendToUser  = User::find(2);
$sendToUser->notify(new JobDenied());
```

I have tried adding the prefix `notifiable_` in the `notifications` table but I ended up getting a new error `Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'` *note the prefix `notifiable_` missing*.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.35

Comment: Possible fix https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/column-notificationsnotifiable-id-not-found-bug

Comment: I tried the last answer. Adding this `return $this->hasMany(\Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification::class) ... ` to the `User Model` but now I get the error: 'user_id column not found'`. Which I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `$table->morphs('php ');` in your notifications migration to `$table->morphs('notifiable');`

Credits goes directly to: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unknown-column-id-in-field-list-laravel-notifications @sutherland

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 8, this was corrected but I still experience this error when I used Model binding to retrieve the model.

```
public function example(Model $model){ $model->notify(new NotificationFile());}
```

Was able to solve it by retrieving the model normally.

```
public function example($slug){ $model = Model::findOrFail($slug); 
$model->notify(new NotificationFile());}
```